# how can I check if the password matches with yup

Tags: reactjs, react-native, yup

I want to use oneOf but it doesnt work. I want to check If the password and password-Repeat matches. In nodejs it works, but in react native it doesnt work. All errors are shown except password-Repeat. Why?

```
const registerSchema = yup.object().shape({
  fullName: yup.string()
  .required('Your name is required.')
  .min(4)
  .max(40),
email: yup.string()
  .required()
  .min(6)
  .max(255)
  .email(),
password: yup.string()
  .required()
  .min(7)
  .max(255),
passwordRepeat: yup.string()
  .oneOf([yup.ref('password'), null], 'Password does not match')
});
```

all my TextInput has values and onChangeText and onBlur and all fields work fine except password repeat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
Yup.object().shape({
  password: Yup.string().required("Required"),
  passwordRepeat: Yup.string()
    .required("Required")
    .when('password', (password, schema) => {
      return schema.test({
        test: (passwordRepeat) => password === passwordRepeat,
        message: 'Password does not match',
      });
    }),
});
```